# Floyd-Warshall with negative loop in C

Tags: c, loops, graph, negative-number, floyd-warshall

im working on graph searching with Floyd-Warshalls algorithm and don´t understand how to alter it to prevent negative loops.

When i enter:

```
From  Cost   To
0      -1     1
1      -2     0
```

I get cost matrix:

```
   0   1
0 -3  -4
1 -5 -10
```

and then it starts looping till it crashes because its still adding negative edges and further decreases the cost.

```
void FloydWarshall(int ***distanceMatrix, int maxVertices)
{
int from, to, via;

for(from = 0; from < maxVertices; from++)
{
 for(to = 0; to < maxVertices; to++)
 {
      for(via = 0; via < maxVertices; via++)
       {
         //Fix the negative looping
         //EDIT FIX:
         if((*distanceMatrix)[via][via]<0)
         {fprintf(stderr, "Contains negative cycle!\n"); continue;}
         //END EDIT
         //Searches for the cheapest way from all-to-all nodes, if new path
         // is cheaper than the previous one, its updated in matrix
         (*distanceMatrix)[from][to] = min((*distanceMatrix)[from][to],
         ((*distanceMatrix)[from][via]+(*distanceMatrix)[via][to]));
       }
 }
}
}
```

Where min is:

```
int min(int a,int b)
{return (a<b)? a:b;}
```

and my distanceMatrix has INF wherever there is no cost.

I came across older topic where the altered algorythm was like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)    // Go through all possible sources and targets

    for(int k = 0; d[i][j] != -INF && k < n; k++)
        if( d[i][k] != INF && // Is there any path from i to k?
            d[k][j] != INF && // Is there any path from k to j?
            d[k][k] < 0)      // Is k part of a negative loop?

            d[i][j] = -INF;   // If all the above are true
                              // then the path from i to k is undefined
```

However, even when i use this fix instead of my function, it still loops and further decreases cost. Is this fix correct? If not, how should i rewrite it? Thanks.

Comment: Invalid setup, you cant have negative cycles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Behavior_with_negative_cycles)

> Hence, to detect negative cycles using the Floyd–Warshall algorithm,
>   one can inspect the diagonal of the path matrix, and the presence of a
>   negative number indicates that the graph contains at least one
>   negative cycle.[2] Obviously, in an undirected graph a negative edge
>   creates a negative cycle (i.e., a closed walk) involving its incident
>   vertices.

So if `d[k][k]` is ever less than `0` you should just exit and say there is a negative cycle.

Comment: Yep, worked. 
Added this instead of  //Fix the negative looping

    if((*distanceMatrix)[via][via]<0){fprintf(stderr, "Contains     negative cycle!\n"); continue;}  This jumps over all negative cycles.  Thanks.